# Tem como fazer um map() de um array de objetos no React?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou fazendo um projeto onde preciso de vários cards de receitas que conterão: título e ingredientes. Esses cards devem ser expansíveis (O usuário verá o título e ao clicar, os ingredientes serão mostrados) e para facilitar, estou usando o Material Ui.

Como não sei a quantidade (a aplicação será dinâmica), gostaria de usar `map()` e notei que precisarei de dois `map()`: Um para os cards e outro para a lista de ingredientes que serão renderizados dentro do card.

Abaixo estão: o exemplo de objeto de entrada que usei para testar, como pensei em fazer a manipulação desse objeto e a mensagem de erro exibida.

### Exemplo de entrada:

```
 const teste2 =[{
   title:"Brigadeiro",
   ingredients:["margarina","achocolatado","leite condensado"]
 },{
   title: "Pão assado",
   ingredients:["pão","margarina"]
 }]
```

### Como pensei em fazer:

```
 const Recipes = (props) =>{
   let recipesList = props.objects.map((object, index)=>{

     let ingrList = object.ingredients.map((ingred,index)=>(
     <CardText expandable={true}>
       {ingred}
     </CardText>
   ))

     return(
       <Card>
         <CardHeader
           title={object.title}
           actAsExpander={true}
           showExpandableButton={true}
         />
         <CardText>
           {ingrList}
         </CardText>
       </Card>
   )})
 }
```

### Erro:

```
 Recipes(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
 Evaluating index.js
```

Alguém teria uma dica do que fazer? Existe algum método `map()` para objetos?

#### Observação:

Tentei separar mais os objetos, criando um só para as listas de ingredientes e renderizando-o dentro dos cards de receitas, porém a propriedade `expandable={true}` do componente `<CardText>`deixa de funcionar (os ingredientes aparecem sempre expandidos). Vale salientar que, nesse teste, não usei objetos.

Comment: O teu código parece-me bem, ondes estás a usar depois esse `Recipes`? Onde está o componente principal e o `render()`?

Answer (score 1):

O erro ocorre por que não há nada sendo retornado do método `render()`. Isso está claro do código e da mensagem de erro.

Aqui vai minha sugestão para resolver o problema: divida a interface de usuário em partes menores. O problema fica mais fácil de resolver. Cada componente ou função deve ter somente uma responsabilidade. Vamos lá:

(1) Crie um componente `Recipes` para todas as receitas.

(2) Crie um componente `Recipe` para só uma receita.

(3) Crie um componente `Ingredient` para cada ingrediente.

**1. Recipes.js**

O componente Recipes só se importa em mostrar vários componentes Recipe.

```
(e.g.
  props.recipes === 
    [
      {
        id: 123,
        title: "Brigadeiro",
        ingredients: ["margarina", "achocolatado", "leite condensado"]
      },
      {
        id: 124,
        title: "Pão assado",
        ingredients: ["pão", "margarina"]
      }
    ]
)
```

---

```
const Recipes = (props) => {
  const recipeComponents = props.recipes.map(recipe => (
    <Recipe key={recipe.id} recipe={recipe} />
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Receitas</h1>
      {recipeComponents}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**2. Recipe.js**

O componente Recipe mostra uma receita individual (e varios ingredientes).

```
(e.g. props.recipe === 
  {
    title:"Brigadeiro",
    ingredients: ["margarina", "achocolatado", "leite condensado"]
  }
)
```

---

```
const Recipe = (props) => {
  const ingredientComponents = props.recipe.ingredients.map(ingredient => (
    <Ingredient key={ingredient} ingredient={ingredient} />
  ));

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader
        title={props.recipe.title}
        actAsExpander={true}
        showExpandableButton={true}
      />
      {ingredientComponents}
   </Card>
  );
};
```

**3. Ingredient.js**

O componente Ingredient tem o papel de renderizar um ingrediente individual.

```
(e.g. props.ingredient === "margarina")
```

---

```
const Ingredient = (props) => {
  return (
    <CardText expandable={true}>
      {props.ingredient}
    </CardText>
  );
};
```

*Nota: todos os imports necessários foram omitidos para focar no problema em questão.*

Answer (score 0):

Fiz com state ao invés de props, se funcionar assim é só trocar depois:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Recipes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            teste2: [
                {
                    title:"Brigadeiro",
                    ingredients: ["margarina","achocolatado","leite condensado"]
                },{
                    title: "Pão assado",
                    ingredients: ["pão","margarina"]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                { this.state.teste2.map((valor, x) => {    
                    return (
                        <CardHeader
                            title={ valor.title }
                            actAsExpander={ true }
                            showExpandableButton={ true }
                            key={ x }
                        />
                        <CardText>
                            { valor.ingredients.map((ingred) => {
                                return { ingred }
                            }) }
                            { ingrList }
                        </CardText>                        
                    )                
                }) }
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const teste2 = [
    {
        title: "Brigadeiro",
        ingredients: ["margarina", "achocolatado", "leite condensado"]
    },
    {
        title: "Pão assado",
        ingredients: ["pão", "margarina"]
    }
]

const Recipes = (props) => {
    const { objects } = props

    const CardContent = objects.map(
        (elem) => {
            <CardHeader
                title={elem.title}
                actAsExpander={true}
                showExpandableButton={true}
            />
            for (ingred of elem.ingredients) {
                <CardText expandable={true}>
                    ingred
                </CardText>
            }
        })
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardContent/>
        </Card>
    )
}
```